# Showing decimal values until its not 0

Tags: php, mysql

This questions is kinda confusing, but here I am telling you the exact problem I have.
In database I have a column with datatype double(10,6), means the value can have upto 6 decimals depending on each user.

Some user have a value 5.22 say in this column.

Now when I echo this value in php, I want it to show 5.22 or 7.256 not 5.220000 or 7.256000.

I hope its clear. 
Thanks.

Comment: @SterlingArcher definitely not a duplicate

Comment: Use `round()` function

Comment: "have a value 5.22 [...] I want it to show 5.22 or 7.256" ..... Hmm??

Comment: Slight nitpick, 5.22 is not the same value as 5.220000.  I'm curious what the use case is here.

Comment: @Jeroen I thought no one gonna say this, that 2 values are for 2 different users, 5.22 for 1st user and 7.256 for 2nd user

Comment: Simplest solution so far I see is using (float)5.220000, returns 5.22